# Большая квадратная  шоколадная конфета? Это неоднородное определение.

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация

Я понимаю, почему неоднородные . потому что характиризует предмет по разным признакам!
но в правиле также говорится -Одно из определений (ближайшее) непосредственно связано с определяемым словом, тогда как второе связано уже со словосочетанием, состоящим из главного слова и первого определения!
 то есть в данном конкретном случае -большая относиться к  сочетанию квадратная шоколадная конфета . а квадратная к шоколодная конфета
но  можно же сказать большая конфета . квадратная конфета шоколодная конфета
не могу понять . почему эти определения непосредственно не связаны с определяемым словом
Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 2):

Большая  квадратная шоколадная конфета. Одно относительное  и два качественных прилагательных, обозначающих разные признаки. Все прилагательные неоднородны.

При очень большом авторском желании можно сблизить признаки "большая, квадратная = необычная" и считать их однородными: большая, квадратная шоколадная конфета.

Любые определения в постпозиции становятся однородными (сближение по общему впечатлению, описание предмета): конфета большая, квадратная, шоколадная.

Answer (score 1):

Сравните:

*Отличная конфета: большая, квадратная, шоколадная.* Однородные определения относятся к слову "конфета" и характеризуют ее преимущества с точки зрения автора. Отличная конфета = большая конфета, квадратная конфета, шоколадная конфета. Все признаки и по отдельности хороши, и вместе.

*На столе лежала большая квадратная шоколадная конфета.* Шоколадная конфета была квадратная - не просто конфета квадратная, а именно шоколадная конфета квадратная (не любую квадратную конфету хочется съесть, я люблю квадратные **шоколадные** конфеты), не просто большая конфета (тоже мне невидаль!), а именно **квадратная шоколадная** конфета большая.

Вы предложили хороший пример. Любимую конфету ни с чем не перепутаешь: только большая квадратная шоколадная конфета как одно целое, а не всякие там "дроби": хочешь квадратную? а большую? а шоколадную?

Однородные определения "суммируются", а неоднородные "нанизываются" друг на друга.

Answer (score 0):

> хочешь квадратную? а большую? а шоколадную?

Отлично! Вместо одной конфеты получилось три))